# SqlServer : Incorrect Results : Number of 'open' issues on a daily basis

Tags: sql, sql-server

I posted this as an earlier question and cleared up some errors.  I am posting a new question as now i'm dealing with bad results.  I'm trying to calculate 'open' issues on given days (ideally between a timeframe but for now just on dates that have entries).

My Data is simplified as: IssueID, CreationDate, CompletionDate

I'd like to tally open issues which is when Year(CompletionDate)=1900 and they are cumulative while they are open, ie: if yesterday there was 1 issue open and today has 1 issue open as well, then today's count of open is 2. They should drop off once they are resolved (Year(CompletionDate) <> 1900). Please help I think i'm close?

I have this returning output correctly on a daily basis only, but it is not accounting for previous issues that are still open at a particular day in time (Legacy_Open_Issue).

```
SELECT
    created_date,
    aOpen_Today + Legacy_Open_Issue - Resolved_Issue as totopen
FROM(
SELECT 
    convert(varchar(10), cast(i.CreationDate as date), 101) as created_date, 
    sum( case when YEAR(i.CompletionDate)=1900 then 1 else 0 end) as aOpen_Today,
    sum( case when (YEAR(i.CompletionDate)<>1900 AND (i.CompletionDate >= i.CreationDate)) then 1 else 0 end ) as Legacy_Open_Issue,
    coalesce(tot,0) as Resolved_Issue
FROM Issues i 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT count(IssueID) as tot, CompletionDate as resolved 
    FROM Issues 
    WHERE YEAR(CompletionDate)<>1900 group by CompletionDate
)x ON  x.resolved = i.CreationDate
GROUP BY convert(varchar(10), cast(i.CreationDate as date), 101), coalesce(tot,0)
) AS y;

My Data is
IssueID CreationDate    CompletionDate
1   1/15/2019   1/1/1900
2   1/16/2019   1/17/2019
3   1/16/2019   1/1/1900
4   1/20/2019   1/21/2019
5   1/28/2019   1/1/1900
6   1/30/2019   1/1/1900


My Output is
created_date    totopen
1/15/2019   1
1/16/2019   2
1/20/2019   1
1/28/2019   1
1/30/2019   1


My Output SHOULD be
created_date    totopen
1/15/2019   1
1/16/2019   3
1/20/2019   3
1/28/2019   3
1/30/2019   4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT DISTINCT CreationDate,DQ.OpenIssues  FROM Issues I
  CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT COUNT(0) OpenIssues FROM Issues I2 
          WHERE I2.CreationDate <= I.CreationDate AND
                     (I.CreationDate < I2.CompletionDate or YEAR(I2.CompletionDate) = 1900)
   ) DQ
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
with i as (
      select creationdate as dte, 1 as inc
      from issues
      union all
      select completiondate, -1 as inc
      from issues
     )
select dte, sum(sum(inc)) over (order by dte)
from t
group by dte
order by dte;
```

This will do a cumulative sum of creations and completions to get the net on each day.

Comment: Sorry what's dte?  nm sorry I see dte

Comment: Thank you I received two answers very close in time.  Yours was very close but started at year 1900 so I will have to choose the other since it worked right off the bat.  Both great approaches I would like to choose both answers but can't.  Thank you for your time!!